# pagination error - laravel Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

```
   public function seguimientos()
{
  // $tracks = Tracking::with(array('order' => function($query)
  // {
  //     $query->where('user_id',Auth::user()->id );
  //
  // }))->get();

  if(!Auth::user()) return abort(404);

  if(!Auth::user()->type == 'admin' || !Auth::user()->type == 'empresa') return abort(404);
  // $trackings = Tracking::all();
  $trackings = Tracking::with('order')->get()->paginate(15);
  $myCompany = Auth::user()->company;
  $statuses = ['Pago exitoso', 'Espera de envio','Pedido en Camino','Pedido Entregado'];

  return view('store.order.admin.seguimiento')->with(['trackings'=>$trackings,'statuses'=>$statuses,'myCompany'=>$myCompany]);
}
```

I try to pag, but I can't get it to work

**blade.php**

```
 <div style="margin-top: -44px;" class="page">


    <ul class="list-group">
        @foreach($trackings as $tracking)
        @if($tracking->order->user->company == $myCompany )
        <li class="list-group-item"> <b>Orden N°:</b> {{ $tracking->order->id }} <a href="{{route('order-show',$tracking->order)}}" class="btn btn-outline-danger btn-rounded tx-danger btn-detalle-pedido"> <b>Detalles</b></a></li>

        </ul>
        @endif
        
        @endforeach
        {{ $trackings->$links() }}  

    <hr>
         
</div>
```

error: Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::paginate does not exist.

in:  `$trackings = Tracking::with('order')->get()->paginate(15);`

help pls

Comment: Try without `get()`

Comment: now the links variable is not correct > Undefined variable: links

Comment: Should be `$trackings->links()` (I am guessing)

Comment: Another question: where is the number of elements to show displayed?

Comment: $trackings = Tracking::with('order')->paginate(15);

Answer (score 0):

You can't use paginate after get so you want to change your code like below.

```
$trackings = Tracking::with('order')->paginate(15);
```